# Cohomology groups on small fppf site and small etale site are not the same

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, schemes

Let $F$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on a scheme $X$. Is there an example where cohomology groups of $F$ on small fppf site of $X$ and small etale site of $X$ are not isomorphic?

Comment: If the scheme is a "usual" scheme (quasi-compact, quasi-separated, etc.), then fppf cohomology, etale cohomology, and Zariski cohomology agree for all quasi-coherent sheaves.